# C - function arguments and "<<" operator

Tags: c, function, operators, constants

i'm sorry for title for being not spesific but i dont know how it's called. here is my question: in [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Library:_POSIX) code snippet, there is constants defined like this:

```
#define WS_NONE     0
#define WS_RECURSIVE    (1 << 0)
#define WS_DEFAULT  WS_RECURSIVE
#define WS_FOLLOWLINK   (1 << 1)    /* follow symlinks */
#define WS_DOTFILES (1 << 2)    /* per unix convention, .file is hidden */
#define WS_MATCHDIRS    (1 << 3)    /* if pattern is used on dir names too */
```

and there is a function defined like this:

```
int walk_recur(char *dname, regex_t *reg, int spec)
```

he sends constants(WS_DEFAULT and WS_MATCHDIRS) to function using "|":

```
walk_dir(".", ".\\.c$", WS_DEFAULT|WS_MATCHDIRS);
```

this is how he uses the arguments:

```
    if ((spec & WS_RECURSIVE))
        walk_recur(fn, reg, spec);

    if (!(spec & WS_MATCHDIRS)) continue;
```

if WS_RECURSIVE passed to function, first if statement will be true. i  didn't get how << operator works and how (spec & WS_RECURSIVE) statement returning true. and how can he sends different constants with "|"? and he can use "spec" value, which must be equal to passed constants, how is that possible?

and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `<<` is bit-shifting left, aka multiply with power of 2.

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia for [**bitwise operations in c**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C), and remember that any non-zero value is treated as `true`

Comment: Also see [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) and [Q: The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list): You need a basic primer on C.

Comment: _Just wondering_ if people looking at C for the very first time (or nearly so) are disqualified to ask a question on this particular stackExchange?  ( I mean, as it stands, without even being edited, the question is clearly stated, with well formatted code, and even includes a real question. yet is down voted twice, and voted to close once already!, WTH)  The only component this post lacks is C expertise.

Comment: +1 @ryyker. i just don't know about "bitwise operations" and i didn't hear how they called. so i decided to ask a question. and this is what happens.

Comment: @ryyker i didn't down vote, but it does lack research. Although it is hard to search for `<<`, searching for "c operators" should do the trick.

Comment: @ ryyker everyone in here using english quite well. i did feel bad about my situation and i said this. but i will take your advice.
@clcto i searched for << operator but i couldn't find any examples like this(using << with | in an if statement confused me, so i decided to ask).

Comment: @ryyker the question title calls it an operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a very common idiom for treating a single integer value as a collection of individual bits. C doesn't have direct support for bit arrays, so we use bitwise operators to set and clear the bits.

The `<<` operator is a left-shift operator. For example:

```
1 << 0 == 1
1 << 1 == 2
1 << 2 == 4
1 << 3 == 8
```

`1 << n` for any non-negative `n` (within range) is a power of 2. Each bit in an an integer value represents a power of 2. Any integer value can be treated as a *unique* sums of powers of 2.

`|` is the *bitwise or* operator; it's use to combine multiple 1-bit values (powers of 1) into an integer value:

```
(1 << 0) | (1 << 3) == 1 | 8
1 | 8 == 9
```

Here we combine bit zero (representing the value `1`) and bit three (representing the value `8`) into a single value `9`. (We could have used `+` rather than `|` in this case, but in general using `|` avoids problems when some power of 2 is given more than once.)

Now we can test whether a bit is set using the *bitwise and* operator `&`:

```
int n = (1<<0) | (1<<3);
if (n & (1<<3)) {
    printf("Bit 3 is set\n");
}
else {
    printf("Bit 3 is not set\n");
}
```

Now we can define macros so we don't have to write `1<<0` and `1<<3` all over the place:

```
#define WS_RECURSIVE    (1 << 0)
...
#define WS_MATCHDIRS    (1 << 3)

int n = WS_RECURSIVE | WS_MATCHDIRS;
// n == 9

if (n & WS_RECURSIVE) {
    // the WS_RECURSIVE bit is set
}

if (!(n&WS_MATCHDIRS) {
    // the WS_MATCHDIRS bit is *not* set
}
```

You could also define macros to simplify setting and testing bits (`SET_BIT()`, `IS_SET()`, etc.), but most C programmers don't bother to do so. Symbolic names for the bit values are important for code readability, but once you understand how the bitwise operators work, and more importantly how the common idioms for setting, clearing, and testing bits are written, the raw operators are readable enough.

It's usually better to use unsigned rather than signed integer types; the behavior of the bitwise operators on signed types can be tricky in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

The `<<` operator is a *bitwise* left shift.

For example, `1 << 0` translates to 1 'left shifted by' 0 bits. This is effectively a nop as 1 left shifted by 0 bits is still the value 1.

To further clarify, let's look at a bitwise representation of a number (lets say the number is a 16 bit value to illustrate)

1 -> 0b'0000000000000001

`1 << 1` would be

2 -> 0b'0000000000000010

And so on.

The `|` operator is a *bitwise* or, so the `WS_DEFAULT | WS_MATCHDIRS` is translated to:

```
0b'0001 | 0b'1000
```

This yields the value `0b'1001` which is then passed to the walk_dir.

If you pass in `WS_RECURSIVE` instead, you will be doing a bitwise and (`&`) operation using two identical values. This will always result in a true value.

AND *Truth Table*

```
 0 & 0 = 0
 0 & 1 = 0
 1 & 0 = 0
 1 & 1 = 1
```

Comment: i cant vote up because of my reputation, thanks and sorry. :)